# Sitecore logging to azure table storage

Tags: sitecore, azure-storage, sitecore8, log4net-appender

Firstly could someone please advise the best practice for sitecore logging when hosted in Azure?

Ideally we would like to log on to table storage. I tried using https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net.Appender.Azure/.

However, the data doesn't stored on to azure table storage until we invoke the buffer.flush() method per article below:
http://zacg.github.io/blog/2014/02/05/azure-log4net-appender/

Has anyone experience this logging on to table storage in sitecore? Any recommendation will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you deploying via the [Sitecore Azure module](https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/azure)? As far as I remember, it has an Azure Table Storage logger set up for you on deploy.

Comment: Nope using custom powershell scripts

Comment: Then look at the Azure module and see how logging is implemented there.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. We have just added a specific object type that is optimized for logging - so our recommendation is to use AppendBlob for logging. See here for more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2015/04/13/introducing-azure-storage-append-blob.aspx.

Unfortunately many people do try to use Table Storage for logging and if you don't design your keys carefully you can end up with hot partitions and scalability problems. Take a look at the logging anti-pattern in this guide: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/.